# How to use the screenshot plugin using the background plugins in phonegap for capturing any screen

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins

How to capture the screen using the Screenshot plugin outside of the app with the help of the background plugin?

I am using this plugin:
 https://github.com/jcrowson/Android-Phonegap-Screenshot-Plugin

Comment: i want to capture the screen using the Screenshot plugin But it will capture the screen which is inside the app not the outside of the app please help me to capture any screen

Comment: Which plugin are you using ?

Comment: https://github.com/jcrowson/Android-Phonegap-Screenshot-Plugin

Comment: Hey @AmitLomte, did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you developping for iOS? Because iOS can be quirky. In Android, it should works.

onPause is native cordova call for when the app goes in background

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html

```
function onPause() {
  navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){}); 
}
```

Don't put any console.log or native call (or loops, intervals), iOS will kill them (and maybe this plugin use native call so you wont be able to call it)

Comment: No I am working for Android, But will it capture the screen outside the app surely